# How can I check my balance using an Italian ATM?

Tags: money, italy

My friend is currently staying in Italy. They are mobile banking and internet banking phobic (they are certain that all their money will be stolen if they use any form of e-banking because, they believe, they are elderly and not tech savvy).

One problem that they face is that when using ATMs in Italy, they don't seem to be able to find out the balance on their account. Do ATMs in Italy allow you to check your balance on a UK account? If so, which banks do so, and what's the Italian label/button for checking your account?

Comment: With some UK banks you seem to be able to bank by telephone, or at least it used to be possible. Maybe they can ask their bank?

Comment: You might be better off with a phone-call to the UK-based bank.

Comment: idk for Italy specifically [so can't provide an answer], but the International system itself does allow for it. I can get my proper UK balance from the 'better' ATMs in Tenerife.

Comment: Don't do that. Any operation in an ATM can be charged, so it's possible that balance check will cost real money. In ATM use only what you must, especially in a one that does not belong to your bank. Use services provided by your bank that you know the rates, like online banking.

Comment: Any advice on the downvote? Can't improve my question(s) without one!

Comment: @Bobsburner Thanks for the edit. Would have been useful for me to specify early on, but there's an answer which addresses the question as originally asked now. Don't want to make the helpful answer look like it didn't address the question!

Comment: You should tell them that ATMs ultimately use an internet connection anyway, many ATMs charge obscene fees, and there's a risk of skimming. Also, many banks offer a way to have read-only access to the account via phone app.

Answer (score 24):

ATMs in Italy (and elsewhere in Europe) typically permit you to change the interface language to English. So there is no need for knowledge of Italian banking terms. Some ATMs even do this automatically if they detect a card issued by an English bank.

So the first step is to get the menus in English.

However, in my experience checking your balance from an ATM abroad is usually not possible. There may be a item on the ATM menu that suggests you can, but if you try to use it you will usually get an error.

Comment: I can't remember whether it worked in Italy (2013), but in Spain (2015-2019), usually I was able to see balance with my American card, but it was stated in Euro.  I did get an error occasionally.

Comment: @WGroleau Are you sure that the ATM showed your actual balance and not the amount available for immediate withdrawal, which if you consider e.g. daily or weekly limits may not be the same. Here in Germany, I can only check my balance if I am at an ATM from my own bank. Even within Germany, ATMs from other banks do not have that data available.

Comment: I can confirm that in Italy you typically cannot see your balance at an ATM. This is something that always annoyed me (I'm Italian but I got used to the banking system abroad). When I needed it for some official reason I had to go inside the bank and ask a teller to print it for me. This might depend on the bank though.

Comment: I am sure.  If they were showing me the daily limit, (1) it wouldn’t be labeled “balance,” and (2) it would be the same amount each time.

Comment: @DenisNardin You can check your balance in any ATM owned by _your_ bank. You simply cannot check your balance from ATMs of other banks.

Comment: @WGroleau just a comment on your first point, I have definitely been abroad and had my available withdrawal amount show up as "balance" on an atm, rather than my actual account balance (not that this is what happened to you)

Comment: I have seen both.   Sometimes without asking.  But there's usually a button to ask, and usually it works.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the ATM interface and capabilities vary widely from bank to bank. Some can offer the ability to change language, some not. Most of them allow you to check you current balance and the list of latest transactions, but it can be limited by the kind of cards you are using. If you are using cards belonging to the Italian ATM circuit (Bancomat/Bancomat POS) you should be fine, but any other card might be not supported.

It is likely that this kind of information is not available on the international circuit, especially if their card is on the Visa or Mastercard circuit and not on the Maestro circuit (a sort of legacy european debit card circuit).

They should look for something like "Servizi bancomat" or "Altri servizi" and then "Lista movimenti" (transaction list) or "Saldo" (balance).

Comment: Thanks for that helpful information!